# How to find and replace a string in all files of a project using netBeans

Tags: netbeans

I have a PHP project in NetBeans

I have a constant named `KEY` and I want to change it to `SECURE` . This constant is spread through out many files of my project. How can I approach this very quickly. I've heard of refactoring, and even tried it but it only renamed the current file and not the whole project's files.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+Shift+H, after clicked on project folder. Lower in dialog you may specify all needed params. As far as it's a constant, you may prefer to specify case match, or if needed, use regular expressions